# Setting a title and favicon for non-html files on a website

Tags: html, node.js, express

Is there a way to set a title and favicon for non-html files on a website? For example, a link like https://example.com/files/image-or-something.png. By default Chrome just sets the title as the URL of the file, and doesn't use the original website's favicon.
This is only relevant for files that can be shown in the browser, like `.png`, `.txt`, etc, since other files are just downloaded automatically (at least on Chrome)
I'm using an Express (Node.js) server, in case there's a server-side solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, this isn't currently possible.

A `.png` file, `.txt`, and anything besides `.html` and `.htm` are **not** websites. They just store what they need to (for example, `.png` stores the image, and only the image). And the only things that can have an image are `.html` and `.htm`, because only websites can have icons and titles.

If you see something other than `.html` and `.htm` with an icon or title, that's the browser parsing the file and turning it into HTML.

Comment: Good explanation, pretty much what I was expecting but nice to know for sure

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers will by default look for a favicon in the root directory for example: http://example.com/favicon.ico. You can use this for a favicon for your images.

Comment: my favicon is in the root directory, but it's also a `.svg`, could this be incompatible?

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem